# Border around extension of 'Run' element

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox

I'm creating a WPF application which shows a list of styled messages.  My goal is to have the contents of multiple styled messages selectable, similar to how you can in Skype:

[image: skype sample]

Currently, I have a ListBox which contains an extension of ListBoxItem that is styled to my needs:

[image]

However, this method does not satisfy my goal of being able to select the text of multiple messages at the same time.  It is only possible to select the text inside one message.

I also tried to put my custom elements inside a RichTextBox control within `BlockUIContainer`s (which is what I suspect I will end up having to use), but the text inside each element cannot be selected, only the entire element:

[image]

Next, I attempted to extend the "Run" element, but I cannot figure out how to put a border around it to style an individual message.

```xml
<Run.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" x:Name="Bd" CornerRadius="2">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Run.Style>
```

With this XAML, I tried to surround the content of the Run using a template, a border element, and a content presenter.  However, the Run control does not appear to support templates.

If anybody could point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you might want to look into adorners.  I believe they are designed for things like this.

Comment: This actually looks like a better solution.  I've never heard of an Adorner before, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but is just another idea...

Use one text control with transparent background so you can select all the text at once. Then you have to draw rectangles behind the text blocks. Like an optical ilussion.
The challenge here is calculating the exactly size of the text rectangle box and the text allignment. My idea is having a predefined sizes and positions design (left text box, right text box, date, etc) so the size and positioning calculations are easier.

Another idea is play with the mouse and/or selection events. During the user text selection replace it programatically with your own selection. The user will think that is he who is selecting the text but is the application who is doing it. Another illusion...

I hope you could resolve it.

Comment: I think you have a good suggestion and that is definitely an option.  One issue would be scrolling, and the rendering performance with a large number of messages.  I'm not sure what you mean by replacing the text selection though?  Thanks for the help.